# Change "Press CTRL + ALT + DELETE to log on" on Windows 7 Lock Screen

Tags: windows-7, lock-screen

Is there any way to change "Press CTRL + ALT + DELETE to log on" to something like: "Press CTRL + ALT + DELETE to make magic" or something like that? This is just for fun.

[image: Sample image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will not claim that this works as I have not tried it, but here is a [proposed solution](http://creativx.net/forums/general-tutorials/90159-how-change-text-ctrl-alt-del-screen-windows-7-a.html) to change that text. It involves some resource hacking and that means **Caveat, this could adversely affect your computer**.

Another thing you can do is to add some [personal messages](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/window-on-windows/adding-messages-to-windows-7s-logon-screen/4390), similar to the motd on an ssh or irc server.

There are also options to [change the background](http://www.techspot.com/guides/224-change-logon-screen-windows7/) if you so desire.

Just make sure to keep track of changes you make so that they can be easily undone if you encounter any problems.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I'll look into it and let you know whether it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to change it with this tool:
http://www.nirmaltv.com/2010/08/27/windows-7-logon-screen-tweaker/

If not, then I have the feeling that you won't be able to change it at all. It wouldn't surprise me if the Windows 7 Secure Logon screen is actually fairly secure.

Answer (score -2):

go to the "Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\User Accounts"

click "Manage User Accounts", then switch to tab "Advanced", you can see what you need:

uncheck "Require users to press Ctrl + Alt + Delete".

Comment: This does not address the question, the OP wants to change the message, not get rid of it.